# I am unable to scroll on minicart dropdown

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How  can I enable scroll or something on minicart? As I tried 1,2 solution for configuration and limit of products to 5 in minicart. but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara  I am using 2.1.8  and there is no tag of it.

Comment: How it is looks like & how you wanted it to look like? put some proper information

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI   when I scroll page start scrolling rather then  Mini cart . Its sticky I think. I want to scroll till end on cart dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a permanent solution but a small fix is as In my case height was auto. 
hope this will help someone.

```
  .minicart-items-wrapper  {
      max-height: 330px !important;
     }
```